# Memory and CPU usage on kill -STOP

Tags: process, memory-usage, kill

I recently learned `kill -STOP` command.

I was wondering, what happens to the data on memory if I do this command.

For example, if I do `kill -STOP` on a process `999` which is taking `20 GB` out of `32 GB` memory, is it safe to launch a process that takes up the same amount of memory?

If it is not safe, is there a way to move memory component to a hard drive, and reload them later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you have disk swapspace for. Linux will page out the least used memory pages when memory runs low. When a process is in STOP state, it's pages will fast be candidate to pageout.

Since disk is much slower than RAM the system can feel slow if it is paging/swapping too much, so enough RAM is always a good thing.

Comment: Thank you! will the whole `20GB` goes  to swap space or only `12GB`?

Comment: @Tom Linux will only page out what there is room for in the swapspace. You can setup compressed swap (zswap) to make swapspace "bigger". Anyway, when you eventually runs out of swap, Linux has an inbuild OutOfMemory killer, that will kill processes so the system doesn't hang up totally.